# Web API not being called from angular

Tags: javascript, angular, observable

I'm trying to call custom API in angular but for some reason it doesn't call it. Before this I made 10 functions in angular (in _api.service.ts) that call web API in the same way and they are correct, my web API is called and data is returned, everything is good. Then I made one more method in web API and one more component in angular (function getList() is called in it), and it didn't work, API is never called.

```js
getList(id: string, chosen: string): Observable<StopListModel[]> {
        let myUrl: string = API_URL + '/stop/list';
        myUrl += '/' + id;
        myUrl += '/' + chosen;
        //debugger goes to this line, url is correct but API not called
        return this.http.get<StopListModel[]>(myUrl, this.httpUtils.getHTTPHeader());
   }
```

When I was debugging I saw that url for API is correctly sent from angular, like in 10 other functions that successfully call API in my project, so I think I don't need to send you code from my web API. I was confused so I moved line that is calling the getList() from new component to existing component, where I already know my _api.service will successfully call web API because in that component there is a function (for example getUsers() ) that correctly calls API. And it didn't work, API is not called for getList().

I assumed there is something wrong with web API for getList(), but just to be sure in that second component I called another _api.service function (that works when called from another component), and surprisingly - API was not called for that function either.

Then I saw what I think the problem is: when I try to call **any** function in **any** of my components, all this "new" functions never call API, just the old ones that have already been there, even though they correctly work in their own components.

```js
export class DetaljiStopoviComponent{
            stops$: Observable<StopStatisticsModel[]>;
            list$: Observable<StopListModel[]>
            constructor(
              private apiService: APIService,
              route: ActivatedRoute
            ) {
                var id = route.snapshot.params['id'];
                this.stops$ = this.apiService.getStopStatistics(id); //this works, it was there before - but any other calling I add under this, API is not called (this is the case for every component, every function)
                this.list$ = this.apiService.getList(id, '3'); //this is the newest one, I can't make it call API even in the empty components      
            }
}
```

I am so confused and not experienced in angular, I'm very courious what the problem is. I don't think something is wrong with web API, but I'm not sure. Does anyone have suggestion?

Comment: In Component, you are calling `apiService.getStopList`, but you attach `getList()` code. Is it the same method?

Comment: Sorry, when editing code to post here (so the names were more understandable), I accidentally left "Stop". this is the same method, just ignore this Stop

Comment: If you place a debugger in `getList`, does it get called? Do you see a call to the URL you want to request?

Comment: yes, debugger goes all the way to return this.http.get..... and url is correct. I know url is correct because when I put it in postman I get correct results back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are forgot to subscribe to:

```
this.stops$ = this.apiService.getStopStatistics(id);
this.list$ = this.apiService.getList(id, '3');
```

I think this.stops$ works for you because somewhere in the template you have async pipe(stops$ | async).

So try to do:

```
this.list$.subscribe(response => console.log(response));
```

after that request should sent

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is a syntax issue, for **get** method try this

```
return this.http.get<StopListModel[]>(myUrl, {headers:this.httpUtils.getHTTPHeader()});
```